# How is it that the github commit activity graph shows different colours when compared to the data fetch from its API

Tags: javascript, api, github, commit, github-api

Problem 1- On the graph, the colours scheme is different from that fetched by the API

[image: example of the graph]

#39d353,#26a641,#006d32,#0e4429

Whereas using the API I was getting these 4 colours -

```
> 0: "#9be9a8" ​​​​​​ 1: "#40c463" ​​​​​​ 2: "#30a14e" ​​​​​​ 
> 3: "#216e39"
```

I know that each block represents a week but still why isn't it the same?

Problem 2- On the graph, the logic for choosing the colour is inverse of what you get thru the API i.e the API data gives you a darker colour for more commits but for the graph the more commits the brighter the colour.

My code:

```
async function getContributions(token, username) {
        const headers = {
            'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`,
        }
        const body = {
            "query": `query {
        user(login: "${username}") {
          name
          contributionsCollection {
            contributionCalendar {
              colors
              totalContributions
              weeks {
                contributionDays {
                  color
                  contributionCount
                  date
                }
                firstDay
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }`
        }
        const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/graphql', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(body), headers: headers })
        const data = await response.json()
        return data
    }

    const getDaily = async () => {
        const data = await getContributions('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', 'anoushk1234')
        
        const conCal = data.data.user.contributionsCollection.contributionCalendar.weeks;
        const todayobj = conCal.pop().contributionDays.pop();
        console.log(data)
```

}

[API Response](https://pastebin.com/AHRp1ugQ)

Comment: If they're getting darker I'd guess the API gives the colours for the light UI scheme.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh yea that does make sense, any idea on how to get the dark and light theme colours?

Comment: Nothing is suggested in https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#contributioncalendarday, I've no particular reason to think they expose both; why not use the contributionLevel to determine your own colour?